# How to write any(s : SequenceType) in Swift

Tags: swift

Swift doesn't seem to have functions for any() or all() so I am trying to make my own.  The closest I have gotten is

```
func any<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element: BooleanType>
    (sequence: S) -> Bool{

    var __g = sequence.generate() 
    var first_element = __g.next()
    if first_element == nil{
        return false
    }
    return reduce(sequence, first_element!, {$0 || $1})
}
```

**Edit**: As per comments, this function should really look like this

```
func any<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element: BooleanType>
    (sequence: S) -> Bool{

    return reduce(sequence, false, {$0 || $1})
}
```

The compiler tells me

```
'S.Generator.Element' is not convertible to 'Bool'
```

It seems to me I am explicitly telling the compiler that it is on the second line.  What am I missing?

Comment: It would be better to use `false` as the initial value for `reduce`. That way, it is simpler and will also work for empty sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `next` returns an optional. That means reduce is expecting to return an optional and `$0` is an optional. You would have to unwrap the optional to be able to use the `||` operator. You also don't know the the type is a `Bool`, just that it is a `BooleanType`. You would have to also convert it to an actual `Bool` by calling `boolValue` on it:

```
func any<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element: BooleanType>
    (sequence: S) -> Bool{

    var __g = sequence.generate() 
    var first_element = __g.next()
    if first_element == nil{
        return false
    }
    return reduce(sequence, first_element!.boolValue, {$0 || $1})
}
```

However, in this case, I think simplicity is best:

```
func any<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element: BooleanType>
    (sequence: S) -> Bool{

    for element in sequence {
        if element.boolValue {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is actually more efficient too because it returns as soon as it finds the first `true` instead of always going through the whole thing.

Comment: I agree that is definitely a better way of doing things.  I don't completely understand what the problem is though and I would like to.  If I add an ! after __g.next() the error changes to "S.Generator.Element is not convertible to 'Bool'

Comment: I think it is a bad error message. I believe the real problem then is that the type of `first_element` is a BooleanType, not a Bool and you are trying to return a Bool. If you call `boolValue` you can convert it to a real Bool

Comment: Is it as efficient as in C#? Meaning would it return the value as soon as it finds the element that returns true or would it cycle through all elements?